# CSS HTML Split paragraph text to column in single tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna make dynamic paragraph column text like this
[image]

but only display in html with :

```
<div>
  <p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora 
  </p>
</div>
```

is that possible to do that in only using single tag `p` on html?

the text will be split when the content height exceeds 125px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add column-count: 2

```
p{ column-count: 2; }
```

check out [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp)

Answer (score 2):

> Add column-count to paragraph.

```css
p{
column-count: 2;
column-gap: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam [do] eius modi tempora 
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach might be to use a row and two columns and display it as flex.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="colmn">
         <p>paragraph one</p>
    </div>

    <div class="colmn">
         <p>paragraph two</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.row{
    display: flex;
}

.colmn{
    flex = 1;
}
```